# Dropdown isn't showing everything in CSS

Tags: html, css, django, django-templates

So I am trying to make a basic nav menu with a drop down from my Django app. My menu is fine, but the dropdown doesn't want to show all the links.

How to fix this?

HTML

```
    <nav role="navigation">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="">Chat Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="" aria-haspopup="true">Go To <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i></a>
          <ul class="dropdown" aria-label="submenu">
            <li><a href="" target="_blank">Calendar</a></li>
            <li><a href=" " target="_blank">Big Blue</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="" style="float: right">Logout</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
```

CSS

```
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background-color: #333;
  position: sticky;
  position: -webkit-sticky;
  width: 100%;
  height: 1.5rem;
}

li {
  float: left;
  font-size: 1rem;
  padding: 0.25rem 1rem;
  letter-spacing: 1.5px;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: block;
  position: relative;
}

li a {
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-align: center;
}

ul li ul li {
  display: block;
  padding: 0.25rem 1rem;
}

li:hover,
li:focus-within {
  background-color: black;
}

li:focus-within a {
  outline: none;
}

ul li ul {
  display: none;
  background-color: #333;
  position: absolute;
  visibility: hidden;
  left: 0;
  margin-top: 2px;
}
ul li:hover > ul,
ul li:focus-within > ul,
ul li ul:hover,
ul li ul:focus {
  display: block;
  visibility: visible;
}
```

You can see what I mean here: https://jsfiddle.net/rj269hsf/

But essentially, when I hover over the "Go To" item it will drop the first listed item below it. The only way to see the second is to move down and hover where it would be, then it shows up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can fix the problem by wrapping the dropdown `<ul>` in a `<div>`. I also gave the nav item with the dropdown the class of `.dropdown-btn` to make the CSS easier to understand.

The `ul li:hover > ul` selector you've used is also incorrect - I replaced it with `.dropdown-btn:hover ul` which selects the `ul` which is a child of `.dropdown-btn` but only when it is hovered.

Lastly, you don't need both `visibility` and `display` to hide the dropdown, simply `display: none` will do.

```css
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background-color: #333;
  position: sticky;
  position: -webkit-sticky;
  width: 100%;
  height: 1.5rem;
}

li {
  float: left;
  font-size: 1rem;
  padding: 0.25rem 1rem;
  letter-spacing: 1.5px;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: block;
  position: relative;
}

li a {
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-align: center;
}

/*ul li ul li {
  display: block;
  padding: 0.25rem 1rem;
}*/

li:hover,
li:focus-within {
  background-color: black;
}

/*li:focus-within a {
  outline: none;
}*/

.dropdown {
  display: none;
  background-color: #333;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  margin-top: 2px;
}
/*ul li:hover > ul,
ul li:focus-within > ul,
ul li ul:hover,
ul li ul:focus {
  display: block;
  visibility: visible;
}*/

.dropdown-btn:hover .dropdown {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<nav role="navigation">
   <ul>
      <li><a href="">Chat Home</a></li>
      <li class="dropdown-btn">
         <a href="" aria-haspopup="true">Go To <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i></a>
         <div class="dropdown">
            <ul aria-label="submenu">
               <li><a href="" target="_blank">Calendar</a></li>
               <li><a href=" " target="_blank">Big Blue</a></li>
            </ul>
         </div>
      </li>
      <li><a href="" style="float: right">Logout</a></li>
   </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: I had tried going the ```<div>``` route initially but it was even more messed up. But your corrections worked out. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You just need to add two properties `width` and `height` to the class `.dropdown` i.e. in your CSS `ul li ul`. [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/p23fq95b/3/)

```
ul li ul {
  /* already mentioned styles */
  width: fit-content;
  width: -moz-fit-content; /* Firefox support */
  height: fit-content;
  height: -moz-fit-content;
}
```